# Exercise about monotonic functions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given
 $$f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ wich is monotonically increasing and $$g(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ wich is monotonically decreasing.

I want to prove that $f$ is continous, I tried to use the definition of continuity but I don't reach anything and the fact that both of them are monotone. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know which types of discontinuities monotonic functions can have?

Comment: First thought: try to use contradiction; what happens if $f$ is not continuous? You can use the monotonicity hypotheses to obtain a contradiction, so $f$ must be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is monotone, at least left and right limit exists at all points. If $f$ is not continuous at, let's say, $x = a$, then we have 
$$
\lim_{x\to a-}f(x) = L_{1} < L_{2} = \lim_{x\to a+}f(x).
$$
Now choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\frac{a+\epsilon}{a-\epsilon} < \frac{L_{2}}{L_{1}}$. Then 
$$
g(a-\epsilon) = \frac{f(a-\epsilon)}{a-\epsilon} \leq \frac{L_{1}}{a-\epsilon} < \frac{L_{2}}{a+\epsilon} \leq \frac{f(a+\epsilon)}{a+\epsilon} = g(a+\epsilon)
$$
which gives a contradiction.

---

The intuition of the solution follows from drawing a graph. $g(x)$ stands for the slope of the line that passes origin and $(x, f(x))$, which may not decrease if $f(x)$ has a 'bump'.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given.
We want to pick $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\epsilon$.
From the two monotonicity properties, we find for $0<\delta<x_0$ and $x_0-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$, that
$$\tag1f(x)\ge f(x_0-\delta)=(x_0-\delta) g(x_0-\delta)\ge(x_0-\delta) g(x_0) = \left(1-\frac\delta{x_0}\right)f(x_0)$$
and
$$\tag2f(x)\le f(x_0+\delta)=(x_0+\delta)g(x_0+\delta)\le (x_0+\delta)g(x_0)=\left(1+\frac\delta{x_0}\right)f(x_0).$$
In particular, by picking $\delta=\frac12x_0$, we obtain $\frac12f(x_0)\le \frac32f(x_0)$, i.e., $f(x_0)\ge 0$.

- If $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$, then we can pick $\delta=\frac12x_0$ an dthen $(1)$ and $(2)$ show $f(x)=0<\epsilon$ for all$x$ in question.
- If $f(x_0)>0$, we can pick $\delta=\frac{x_0\epsilon}{2f(x_0)}$ and then $(1)$ and $(2)$ show $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le\frac\epsilon2<\epsilon$.